# Showing special characters in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, utf-8

This seems to be ever lasting problem of showing special characters in HTML.

I am using PDO with mysql and PHP, the collation in mysql is `utf8_unicode_ci`  .

Here is this sentence and name saved in database.

```
"I can't go to school
```

When I make a select query and echo it in my HTML file ,it appears like this

```
â€œI can't go to school
```

I have set `$PDO->exec("set names utf8");` that should make that the response received should handle the special characters.

Moreover my HTML has this on top when I view the viewsource via browser

```
<meta content="charset=utf-8">
```

I suppose there could be two reasons, either the data is not fetched properly or it is fetched properly but not displated properly in View,

how can I solve/debug that ?

Comment: Did you try `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");`?

Comment: @DavidDomain this probably does the same thing , $PDO->exec("set names utf8");, but let me try the one you mentioned too.

Comment: What PHP version are you on? To use `charset=UTF8` in constructor you need to run v.5.3.6 or above. Prior to PHP 5.3.6 you had to do manually as you did.

Comment: @DavidDomain still sam

Comment: Last option i can think of is driver specific one for `mysql`. Here you go `new PDO(
    'mysql:host=mysql.example.com;dbname=example_db',
    "username",
    "password",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`, hope this does the trick.

Comment: @DavidDomain much better but now it shows like this I can't go to school, it ate my "

Comment: @Marc B , I wont regard it as duplicate , the other question emphasizes on utf8mb4

Comment: @SmartMindx: doesn't matter what charset you settle on, it just has to be the SAME charset throughout, unless you put charset translation logic at the "borders" of each stage.

Comment: @MarcB I would like to ask a short question, I dont want to open another thread for this, lets save I have to save word U'SA in database, How we should save this exactly, U'SA or U\'SA? just give me short answer how google, facebook , SO stores and eager to know the official way . thnx

Comment: @DavidDomain sorry for pinging, but I can add just one user on comments, please see the short question above,

Comment: @SmartMindx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @MarcB my question was something else, I am also using PDO with prepared queries, my question was about end result, In DB, what should be the state of data, U'SA or U\'SA ?

Comment: if you have `insert ... values('U\'SA')`, then you'll get `U'SA` in the table. escaping is like wrapping paper. the db "unwraps" the data for insertion into the table.

Comment: `â€œ` is the mojibake for `“`.   - The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
 - You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
 - The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  (It should have been `utf8`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try change your sentence

```
"I can't go to school
```

to this

```
\"I can\'t go to school
```

Comment: that doesn't sounds a long term solution.